# NSIS uninstall page custom function already defined

Tags: nsis

When I use script like this it's ok:

```
...
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
...
```

But when I use this one script I've got error - !define: "MUI_UNPAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE" already defined!

```
...
!define MUI_UNPAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE un.onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
!define MUI_UNPAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE un.onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
...
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_*` defines are per-page and the !insertmacro call that creates the page will undefine `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_*` after using their contents. `MUI_UNPAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE` is not a MUI define and will remain after the macro and when you try to define it again you get a normal compiler error...